# Android 6.x Webview undefined when switching context

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to automate mobile app in **android** (6.0.1) using **appium**.  i am getting error as

> No such context found.

While switching from Native to Webview,I am getting Webview as

> WEBVIEW_undefined

Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new UIautomator you don't need to switch your driver to webview. It has built in capabilities to identify the elements inside webView.

Please update your Android SDK once.

And also you can see the elements inside webView on Android 6.0+ devices using UIAutomator.

Comment: I need to automate in 5.0 and 5.1 OS versions also. For that i have to switch it to webview. Therefore i am trying to write a script which will be applicable to automate in multiple OS versions

Comment: @akashmahato Even if you want to run on different versions of Android, you don't need to switch the driver to webview, it automatically handles that.  Automate the script using a device with OS Version 6.0+ and after automating the same script for other versions(5.0 or 7.0). It will work on all versions. I am doing the same thing.

Comment: @Vinod I fail to find any further info on this. Care to elaborate on how exactly to use CSS selectors without switching to web context? Thanks!